# Declare the scalar variable @Username

Tags: c#, variables, declare, scalar

```
SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Daniel\source\repos\ExploringSpace\Db\Login.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
    SqlCommand scmd = new SqlCommand();
    private void LgnBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(txtUsers.Text == "" && txtPasss.Text == "" && txtComPass.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Fields Empty Please try again");
        }

        else if(txtPasss.Text == txtComPass.Text)
        {
            sqlcon.Open();
            scmd.Connection = sqlcon;
            string register = "INSERT INTO [dbo.Table] (Username,Password) VALUES (@Username,@Password)";
            scmd = new SqlCommand(register, sqlcon);
            scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUsers.Text);
            scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPasss.Text);
           
            scmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            
            sqlcon.Close();
            this.Hide();
            Form2 fm2 = new Form2();
```

I have tried everything but still not working
It says I must declare the scalar variable
It is a register form in C#
I have done the login and it works.

Comment: Does it work if you hard code a value for Username instead of pulling from the textbox?

Comment: Nope it doesn't work

Comment: I don't see how you could get that error if the 'else if' statement is executing. Are you sure it isn't dropping into another condition that you haven't shown here?

Comment: Why you twice create command? Please write exactly the error you are getting.

Comment: why where is it

Comment: Not a solution to your problem but I believe you should use `||` instead of `&&` in your first check.

Comment: Is there more code with SQL commands in it? By the way, issues with your code: sqlcon and scmd should not be cached, dispose with using instead. [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), declare parameter types and lengths. Your connection string should not be hard-coded, also see [Bad habits: Using AttachDBFileName](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-attachdbfilename)